# "When a File is deleted" with Trigger condition and Folder defined will never get triggered

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform

I have this flow which should run when a folder is deleted inside a folder inside sharePoint online document library:-

[image: main.PNG]

with those 2 trigger conditions for the IsFolder & Path, as follow:-

[image: 2cond.PNG]

but the flow will never get executed/run.. i tried to remove one of the trigger conditions as follow:-

[image: 1cond.PNG]

but still the flow will never run. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions must be true.

`IsFolder` and `Equals` are already methods returning `true` or `false`.

So, you do not need to test `@equals` with `true`.

Also, there is an error syntax in your condition: it's `body/IsFolder` and not `body/{IsFolder}`

Condition should be:

```
@triggerOutputs()?['body/IsFolder']
```

The second condition to check a specific folder is already handled by the `Folder` parameter of the trigger.

[image: flow definition]

[image: flow condition]

I test on my side:

- when I'm deleting a file: no flow
- when I'm deleting a folder outside the specific folder: no flow
- when I'm deleting a subfolder inside the folder: flow is running!

Comment: thanks for the reply, i always use {} inside the trigger conditions without any issues

Comment: i tried you code but it did not work.. not sure

Comment: Oh, it’s weird. Maybe the user (connected to the trigger) has exceeded the quota of execution for the day? Without the condition, is it working?

Comment: One note: the folder parameter must start by the list URL. In my screenshot /Documents partages/F1: "Documents partages" is the URL of the document library called "Documents" and "F1" is the root folder.

Comment: Do you finally succeed to make things working?