# Should/Can we use {} inside Trigger Conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Inside the web i found many syntax for writting Trigger Condition for automated flow, some uses this syntax:-

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{IsFolder}'],true)
```

while other uses this syntax without {}:-

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/IsFolder'],true)
```

so are syntax valid?

Comment: I’ve never seen the first approach used. Why don’t you simply test it? That will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to determine the right syntax is to use the `Peek code` button in Power Automate studio with a `Compose` action. So you will get the generated code. It could be useful when trying to set trigger conditions (as replied in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677738/10263175)

In your case, the valid syntax is:

```
@triggerOutputs()?['body/IsFolder']
```

As @Skin also commented, I **never** seen the first one with curly bracket, even if you said it's working.

[image: peek code]

[image: view code]